# Ant task to copy a file if it doesn't exist at the target location

Tags: ant, build, build-automation

Is there any Ant task that copies a file to a target location only if the file doesn't exists at the target Location ?

Answer (score 8):

There are three cases:

1. The target file doesn't exist.
2. The target file exists but is older than the source file.
3. The target file exists and is newer than the source file.

This question is asking for the copy to happen only in case 1. The default is for the copy to happen in cases 1 and 2; setting overwrite to true makes the copy happen in all three cases. The answer is to use a `present` selector:

```
<copy todir="dest">
  <fileset dir="src">
    <present present="srconly" targetdir="dest" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Answer (score -1):

The [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) has an overwrite attribute which is default set to false.

> overwrite = Overwrite existing files even if the destination files are
>   newer. Required=No; defaults to false.

So you're fine with the copy task when overwrite="false" (which is default), means :

```
  <copy todir="../dest/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir">
      <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
```

or for a single file :

```
<copy file="myfile.txt" todir="../some/other/dir"/>
```

does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Does only work if the source file is not newer than the destination file. If it is newer, the destination file gets overwritten.

Comment: @Subby you're right, IMO a bug. From the source of copy task :                 if (forceOverwrite || !destFile.exists()
                    || (file.lastModified() - granularity
                        > destFile.lastModified())) {
                    fileCopyMap.put(file.getAbsolutePath(),
                                    new String[] {destFile.getAbsolutePath()});
                } else {
                    log(file + " omitted as " + destFile
                        + " is up to date.", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);  => it's obvious why

Comment: What happens if target folder does not exist? Will it create a target folder?

Comment: @vogash Yes, it behaves similar to shell mkdir command with -P parameter.

Comment: @Rebse I don't think it's a bug to be honest. It's in the documentation.